# Azure Data Factory: Update .csv file on Azure Storage with Azure Batch Custom step with Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

The ADF pipeline's aim is to use a Control File, which looks like the following:
[image]

This is stored on ADLS Gen2 as a .csv blob file. The files indicated in the Control File must be processed and for each file, update the Control File with new columns.

```
def updateCF(v, cf, cfPath, sourceFileName, CDFileName, CDLDate):
    connectionString = v.storage['connectionString']
    containerName = v.storage['containerName']

    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connectionString, container_name=containerName, blob_name=cfPath)
    
    cf['cdl_filename'] = np.where(cf['source_filename'] == sourceFileName, CDFileName, "")
    cf['cdl_date'] = np.where(cf['source_filename'] == sourceFileName, CDLDate, "")
    cf.to_csv(cfPath, sep=';', index=False)

 
        try:
            blob.upload_blob(cfPath,blob_type=BlobType.AppendBlob)
        except:
            blob.append_block(cfPath, length=len(data))
```

Using the above piece of code results in the following error:

> azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: The blob type is invalid
> for this operation.

How can I do this to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: The blob type is invalid for this operation.

The above error occurs if you are trying to perform an **`append operation on a block blob`**, you will get this error because append operations are only supported on append blobs.

My sample input data:

[image]

Now you can use the below code to upload CSV with append blob type.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def updateCF():
    cf = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\xxx\demo.csv")
    cf['cdl_filename'] = np.where(cf['Column1'] == "Value46", "sample.txt", "")
    cf['cdl_date'] = np.where(cf['Column1'] == "Value46", "22-08-2023", "")
    cf.to_csv('abfs://filesystem2@venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/sample326.csv',mode='a',storage_options = {'account_key' : 'your-storage-account-key'})
updateCF()
```

**Output:**
[image]

You can read the file using the below code:

**Code:**

```
import  pandas  as  pd
tmp=pd.read_csv('abfs://filesystem2@venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/sample326.csv',storage_options  = {'account_key' : 'your-account-key'})
print(tmp)
```

**Output:**

```
   Unnamed: 0  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5 cdl_filename    cdl_date
0            0   Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4   Value5          NaN         NaN
1            1   Value6   Value7   Value8   Value9  Value10          NaN         NaN
2            2  Value11  Value12  Value13  Value14  Value15          NaN         NaN
3            3  Value16  Value17  Value18  Value19  Value20          NaN         NaN
4            4  Value21  Value22  Value23  Value24  Value25          NaN         NaN
5            5  Value26  Value27  Value28  Value29  Value30          NaN         NaN
6            6  Value31  Value32  Value33  Value34  Value35          NaN         NaN
7            7  Value36  Value37  Value38  Value39  Value40          NaN         NaN
8            8  Value41  Value42  Value43  Value44  Value45          NaN         NaN
9            9  Value46  Value47  Value48  Value49  Value50   sample.txt  22-08-2023
10          10  Value51  Value52  Value53  Value54  Value55          NaN         NaN
11          11  Value56  Value57  Value58  Value59  Value60          NaN         NaN
12          12  Value61  Value62  Value63  Value64  Value65          NaN         NaN
13          13  Value66  Value67  Value68  Value69  Value70          NaN         NaN
14          14  Value71  Value72  Value73  Value74  Value75          NaN         NaN
15          15  Value76  Value77  Value78  Value79  Value80          NaN         NaN
16          16  Value81  Value82  Value83  Value84  Value85          NaN         NaN
17          17  Value86  Value87  Value88  Value89  Value90          NaN         NaN
18          18  Value91  Value92  Value93  Value94  Value95          NaN         NaN
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Tutorial: Use Pandas to read/write ADLS data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool#readwrite-data-using-secondary-adls-account)

Comment: Hi :) Should this also work if I create a csv blob file in chunks and want to add 50000 new rows in each iteration of a for loop? :) Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: I am not sure about this. You can raise a new question on this platform so that the community can help you with your requirement.