# Azure Data Factory, Batch Service, Python: Unable to append blob with csv chunks

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage, azure-batch

Azure Data Facory pipeline runs a Custom activity with Batch Service as a linked service, which holds Python code in it. The transformation was built for running locally, and I want to make it work on Azure, saving blobs (csv files) into Azure Storage (Az Data Lake).

The transformation runs on chunks, and performed within a for loop.

```
for i, in_chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source, chunksize=6000, sep=";")
    # transformation happens and spits out out_chunk parameter 
    # holding the 6000 rows out of the entire file
    kwargs = {'mode':'a', 'header': False} if i>0 else {}
    out_chunk.to_csv(cdl_file, sep="|", index=False, **kwargs)
```

After this, I tried different approaches as it is written in this question and answer for example: [My original question for another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76952568/azure-data-factory-update-csv-file-on-azure-storage-with-azure-batch-custom-st/76953595?noredirect=1#comment136616838_76953595)

The solution written in the question and the answer above didn't throw errors, but it didn't store the entire file, only the 6000 rows specified as a chunk.

What am I doing wrong? I do not understand how should this be handled.

EDIT: As requested by JayashankarGS, I added the code I tried and the screenshot about what happened.

```
def transform_data(v, outputType, eventType, fileName, config, source, conn_string, dl, encoding, in_dtypes = None,  chunkSize=10000, in_sep = ";"):
folderName = 'temp'
containerName = 'input'
outputBlobName = folderName + "/" + fileName
inputBlobPath = containerName + "/" + outputBlobName
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string, container_name=containerName, blob_name=outputBlobName)

credential = {'connection_string': conn_string}
accountName = conn_string.split("AccountName=")[1].split(";")[0] 

adls_path = 'abfs://' + containerName + '@' + accountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/' + outputBlobName

template = pd.DataFrame(columns = v.headers[outputType])
transformationSchema = config[outputType + "_out_transformations"]

logging.info('Reading data chunk...')
for i, in_chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source,
            chunksize = chunkSize,
            sep=in_sep,
            encoding = 'unicode_escape',
            dtype=in_dtypes)):
    logging.info('Handle duplicates and missing fields...')

    in_chunk.fillna('', inplace=True) 
    out_chunk = template.copy()

    out_chunk.fillna('', inplace=True)

    out_chunk.drop_duplicates(subset=[config["composite_key"]["key_partA"], config["composite_key"]["key_partB"], config["composite_key"]["key_partC"]],inplace=True)

    logging.info('Start data transformation for schema: ' + outputType)

    for name, spec in transformationSchema.items():
        out_chunk[name] = transform_column(in_chunk, spec)

    kwargs = {'mode': 'a', 'header': False}

    logging.info('Transformation was successful for ' + outputType)
    dateTime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

    if not os.path.exists(containerName + "/" + folderName + "/"):
            os.mkdir(containerName)
            os.mkdir(containerName + "/" + folderName + "/")

    print(f"Uploading chunk: {len(out_chunk)}")
    logging.info('Trying to store transformed file in Azure Storage...')

    out_chunk.to_csv(adls_path, storage_options=credential, sep=dl, index=False, **kwargs)
```

The result of this is two files generated and stored in Azure Storage. As you can see in the results of running this with Batch Service on Azure Data Factory, it processes 10000 rows as given batch size, and then tries to do the same for the second file. The "file not found" error comes from a step after transformation which is a validator (ignore that warning!).

[image]

Comment: Why are you going with chunk size. As i can see the solution given for your previous question uploads the entire csv to azure datalake directly.

Comment: Chunking was implemented for the transformation of the file because otherwise 4GiB of data needs to be processed in one round. This is a different file processing type, and would like to try and keep the chunking if possible - but not sure how to solve the issue then :)

Comment: Is this code working fine in local?

Comment: Locally it was working like that it stores the chunk in a local csv file after processing and eventually did so with the entire file. So I tried to make this work similarly just to store it into a blob storage :) I'm unsure if that is actually a possibility though...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is having different blob types.

In your code:

```py
adls_path = 'abfs://data@jgsblob.dfs.core.windows.net/outfromVS.csv'
credentials = {'connection_string': blob_conn}

for i, in_chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('./hts-sample-test.csv', chunksize=500, sep=";")):
    kwargs = {'mode': 'a', 'header': False} if i > 0 else {}
    print(in_chunk.count())
    in_chunk.to_csv(adls_path, storage_options=credentials, **kwargs)
```

For the first iteration, you are not passing the `mode`; by default, this makes the file of type **Block blob**.

[image]

When you are writing to storage, the **BlobType** should be the same.

So, just give the mode from the start:
`kwargs = {'mode': 'a', 'header': False}`

Below is the count of my data:

[image]

Now uploading with a chunk size of 500:

```py
for i, in_chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('./hts-sample-test.csv', chunksize=500)):
    kwargs = {'mode': 'a', 'header': False}
    print(f"Uploading chunk: {len(in_chunk)}")
    in_chunk.to_csv(adls_path, storage_options=credentials, **kwargs)
```

Output:
[image]

and

[image]

Again, getting the file:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure the output file is not present in the storage account when you are running it first time, if it is present, it should be of **Append blob** type.

Comment: Ok it became an append blob but it doesn't add more than the chunk size to it - it stops running after it uploaded the first chunk. Should the file be reopened every time a new chunk needs to be appended to it?

Comment: Add the output screenshot in the question. Along with the code you trying.

Comment: I updated the question as you requested, let me know if you need further information :)

Comment: Are you able to see the output file in destination? Check the logs to see exactly where you are getting this error. After uploading 10000 records it is not able to upload further, it seems in 2nd iteration something going wrong.

Comment: It is happening right after the first iteration! So it reads in the chunk, transforms and saves to storage, and then it doesn't run the next iteration...

Comment: What is the output in `stderr.txt`? and what are you passing to `source`?

Comment: The source is the content of a csv blob file. The output of the stderr.txt does not throw errors, only returning the logging messages. It is visible that the for loop only did one iteration.

Comment: Source is content or path?  Are you trying to read any file in  `transform_column(in_chunk, spec)` function? I've tried in environment with batch activity it's working fine. You need to debug and try reducing chunk size.

Comment: Source is actually a path - sorry for the confusion. It's not a content. The source is the path for a blob which is read straight from storage account - well loaded into the working directory in the batch job. I reduced the chunk size earlier and the same behavior I've seen. What issue do you think I should pay attention to?

Comment: using `pd.read_csv` check the number of records are matching to source file.

Comment: I don't understand. Would you change the chunk size based on the number of records in the source file?

Comment: Check number of records in source file and use `len(pd.read_csv(adls_path,credentials))` to get number records uploaded in destination. check if it is same. because in your code somewhere you are trying to access file which is not present. Try uploading to blob storage locally before trying it in batch activity.

Comment: your chunk size should be less than the number of records, if it is more, in a single loop it uploads all the data.